# How to access a field from mysql table from url with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, xml

Hi im trying to access a field from a mysql table results from a url eg localhost/test.php=id=2

btw im noob to xml and php so please excuse me for that..

any suggestions or tutorials would be gratefully appreciated..

heres the code im working on

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: text/xml"); 
 $xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
 $xmlBody .= "<XML>";

 $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
 $dbuser = 'nas';
 $dbpass = 'root';
 mysql_select_db('db_home') or die("no database");

 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_gas ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$id = $row["gas_id"]; 
$timestamp = $row["timestamp"];  
$value = $row["value"]; 
$datetime = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["datetime"])); 
$xmlBody .= '
<Data> 
<DataID>' . $id . '</DataID> 
<DataTime>' . $timestamp . '</DataTime>
<DataValue>' . $value . '</DataValue>
<DataTime>' . $datetime . '</DataTime>
</Data>';
} 
mysql_close(); 
$xmlBody .= "</XML>";
echo $xmlBody; 
?>
```

when i put this into the address bar local/xmltest.php?DataID=2 i get a blank screen..

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: As mentioned in the @developerwjk's answer. Add `$DataID = $_GET['DataID'];` above the sql query. In your actual sql query add `WHERE id = '$DataID'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly fix your url as developerwjk suggests. so;

```
localhost/test.php?id=2
```

also im assuming DataID is the id of the table_gas entry you want to get it.

maybe try;

```
$DataID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['DataID']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_gas WHERE gas_id = ".$DataID." ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
```

This will get only the row specified in the url.

I would suggest however moving onto MySQLi as MySQL is soon to be depreciated,
and also move onto parametrized queries to improve security.

So something like.

```
$DataID = $_GET['DataID'];
$q = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_gas WHERE gas_id = ? ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0, 20")
$q->bind_param("i", $DataID);
$q->execute();
$q->bind_result($id, $timestamp, $value, $datetime);
while($q->fetch()){
    $xmlBody .= '
      <Data> 
          <DataID>' . $id . '</DataID> 
          <DataTime>' . $timestamp . '</DataTime>
          <DataValue>' . $value . '</DataValue>
          <DataTime>' . $datetime . '</DataTime>
      </Data>';
}
```

Hope this helps, and seriously, look into MySQLi, even if you dont use the OO approach with it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use `mysql_` anymore. I personally like PDO so here's my answer

As mentioned below, the url should be `localhost/xmltest.php?DataID=2`

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
$xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$xmlBody .= "<XML>";

$dbhost = 'localhost'; //No need to set the port if default is 3306
$dbuser = 'nas';
$dbpass = 'root';
$dbname = 'db_home';

// Check if ?id= is set or not
if ( isset($_GET['DataID']) ) {
    // Initiate the connect to the MySQL DB using PDO extention. You'll need to activate PDO if it's not done then restart Apache
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='. $dbhost .';dbname='. $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_gas WHERE id = :id ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $_GET['DataID']); // Grab the value inside ?id= and pass it in the query
    $query->execute(); // Execute the query with the parameters
    $result = $query->fetchAll(); //Fetch everything and store it in a variable

    foreach ($result as $row) { // I like using foreach but while loop works too
        $xmlBody .= '
        <Data> 
        <DataID>' . $row["gas_id"] . '</DataID> 
        <DataTime>' . $row["timestamp"] . '</DataTime>
        <DataValue>' . $row["value"] . '</DataValue>
        <DataTime>' . strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["datetime"])) . '</DataTime>
        </Data>';
    }
    $xmlBody .= "</XML>";
    echo $xmlBody; 
} else {
    echo "Invalid ID."; //Output error message if test.php?id= is not set
}
```

Comment: hi im getting the following error Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /var/www/xxx.php on line 24 any suggestions .. thanks

Comment: My bad, I made a typo it should be `:id` instead of `:uid` on the line `$query->bindParam(':uid', $_GET['DataID']);` I modified the code

Comment: Haha, really sorry for that once again. I made a mistake in the query. It happens when I answer this when I am half awake.

Comment: no luck sorry again.. http://192.168.1.111/yyy.php?DataID=2 im still getting a blank screen

Comment: 1 gas_id int(16)   No None AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change  Drop Drop  More Show more actions
  2 timestamp timestamp  on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  Change Change  Drop Drop  More Show more actions
  3 value int(20)   No None   Change Change  Drop Drop  More Show more actions
  4 datetime datetime   No None   Change Change  Drop Drop  More Show more actions

Comment: What? I have no idea what you just posted. Can you make a clear table or screenshot of your table in your original post?

Answer (score 0):

The URL `localhost/test.php=id=2` is invalid.  It should be `localhost/test.php?id=2`

The ? mark start the parameter list for a GET request. You retrieve the value of the parameter by `$_GET['id']`

If you get a blank screen, its probably a syntax error in your PHP, but you have error reporting off.  For your development server you should turn error reporting on to see what that is. See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: thanks for the reply, im still getting a blank screen :-( does the code look ok ?

Comment: i cant find the php.ini file do you know where it is located ?

Comment: under the installation path for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
mysql_select_db('db_home') or die("no database");

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
```

You're actually trying to select a database while you're not even connected to server yet.

Try the other way around instead:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_home') or die("no database");
```